# Hello, I am trying to figure out how to run VS code on my mobile

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have seen some articles and files on github and the such that said i could do it, but I'm struggling to figure it out. An explanation of how to do it and how it actually works would be fantastic.

Comment: Visual Studio and Visual Studio Code are different things. Please be careful with your tags.

Comment: My question is why? Just because you can doesn't mean you should or that it would be a good experience.

Comment: Because i am working on coding projects with a partner and we have one pc, i wish to also help with trouble shooting the code but i cannot do so while he does.